# Wait promise finish in outer function

Tags: angular

Im working with Ionic2 + Laravel.
Im trying to make a "interceptor" that will put on Header the token (JWT) for auth from LocalStorage in all my Http requests.
So, i made a Service with a method:

```
post(url : string, json : any) : Observable <\Response> {

    var headers = new Headers();
    var token = null;
    this.local.get("token").then( (tk) => {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tk);
        var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        token = tk;
    });

    -> wait the 'token' != null <-
    return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify( json ), options);
}
```

the problem is:
I'm expecting a "*Observable<\Response> http.post()*" return when call post() from this service.
But, i need that "*this.local.get()*" Promise finish the resolve because i need the token from LocalStorage to append on Header.
How can i make the "*this.local.get()*" Promise, get the token, so, declare the Observable http.post() and return it? (to outer function)
I just can't find a way to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks :DD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The key is in your call to the `then()` method on Promise objects. Unlike `done()` (which returns `undefined`), `then` returns another promise whose value resolves to the value returned by the function passed as an argument to `then`. You can take advantage of this twice: once to pass your token to the `http.post()` call, and again to return the whole promise out of your `post()` function:

```
post(url : string, json : any) : Observable <\Response> {

    var headers = new Headers();
    return this.local.get("token").then( (tk) => {
        headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + tk);
        var options = new RequestOptions({headers: headers});
        return tk;
    }).then(tk){
        return this.http.post(url, JSON.stringify( json ), options);
    };
}
```

Comment: wow, thanks quickly answer. Already tried it. As i say, im expecting a  Observable <\Response> return. So, i got the Typescript error: "Error TS2322: Type 'Promise<any>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<Response>'"

Comment: Even if i remove the return type, i got a error like "Property 'map' does not exist on type 'Promise<any>'" cause im calling ->map( ) and map is a Observable<Response> funcion (not a Promise<any>)

Comment: lastly, i try to cast the return with <Observable<Response>>, and i got "Neither type 'Promise<any>' nor type 'Observable<Response>' is assignable to the other" =////

Comment: It's because `then()` is returning a Promise with `http.post()`'s Observable in it. You'll need to return the value that the promise resolves to. Either that, or you'll have to figure out how to (non-trivially) convert your Promise to an Observable.